# How do I search JSON data originating on another server using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have data to search through. I am writing a directory app in AngularJS that takes JSON data from one of our servers; an employee list. I need to be able to do a live search on that data, but nothing I have tried seems to work. Specifically, the view does not update.

Code: `app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('directory', ['ngRoute']);

app.service('DirectoryService', ['$http', function($http){
var baseURL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/accounts/people/json";

return{
    getEmployees: function() {
        return $http.get(baseURL).then(function(response){
            return response.data;
        });
    }
}
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/employees', {
        templateUrl: '_common/partials/list.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/employees' 
    });
}]);

app.controller('DirectoryController', ['$scope', 'DirectoryService',            
function($scope, DirectoryService){
    $scope.searchName = '';
    DirectoryService.getEmployees().then(function(data){
        $scope.employeeList = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

Code: `list.html`

```
<div id="searchSection">
<input id="searchValue" type="text" placeholder="Search by Name" ng-
model="searchName" />
</div>
<div id="listView">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='employee in employeeList | filter: {name:searchName}'>

    <p>{{employee.name}}</p>

    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: First ensure data is coming from server or not.

Comment: Is the space in `ng- model` (between the hyphen and the m) in the input field intentional?

Comment: Nope, that's unique to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

When I've added filters I simple add an input with ng-model:

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="searchFilter" placeholder="Filter..." />
```

Then in my ng-repeat:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="user in usc.users | filter:searchFilter">
<tr>
{{user.name}}
</tr>
</tbody>
```

That should filter through all the names.

Comment: I tried that first...doesn't work...can't determine why. There's something obvious that I'm not seeing. But, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a factory for your service, have the service hold the data for you, and reference it in your controller.  Something along these lines should work:

```
app.factory('DirectoryService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var service = {};
  service.data = {
    baseURL:"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/accounts/people/json",
    employeeList:[],
    searchName:""
  }

  service.getEmployees = function() {
    $http.get(service.data.baseURL).success(function(response) {
      service.data.employeeList = response;
    })
  }

  return service;
}])
```

Then your controller function can reference the service's data, which will dynamically update:

```
app.controller('DirectoryController', ['$scope', "DirectoryService", function($scope, DirectoryService) {
  $scope.ds = DirectoryService.data;
  DirectoryService.getEmployees();
}])
```

So your relevant HTML function should look like this:

```
<input id="searchValue" type="text" placeholder="Search by Name" ng-model="ds.searchName" />

<li ng-repeat="employee in ds.employeeList | filter:{name:ds.searchName}">
  <p>{{employee.name}}</p>
</li>
```

Comment: This makes sense, but it's not working. I cannot figure out why. $scope.ds contains all the right data...but the view isn't updating

Comment: My immediate thoughts would be something is wrong with the filter.  Try taking the filter off and seeing if that does anything.

Comment: Also, if you're using my code exactly, make sure you include your original line defining `$scope.searchName = "";` at the top of the controller, I edited the code to reflect the need to define this variable.

Comment: No change. It's still not updating the view.

Comment: So the unordered list is just not displaying at all?

Comment: I used your code, more or less unaltered with the exception of a comma at the end of "baseURL..." and the inclusion of $scope.searchName.

Comment: Yes, it's displaying. But typing anything in to the search box does not update the view.

Comment: Okay, let's try moving the searchName into the service too, I'm posting updated code.

Comment: Still not updating the view. I am mystified at this point. Baffled.

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to wrap the response in $rootScope.$apply()...or otherwise force the call

Comment: Yea this is extremely strange. The last thing I was thinking is that the searchName variable was out of scope, but putting it in the service should have fixed it. Maybe someone else can see what we're not, but I'm thinking the text box isn't updating the variable.

Comment: Well, regardless....thanks for the help. I've only been working with angular for a couple of months. This sort of thing can get frustrating.

Comment: If you do figure it out, I'd be very interested in the answer. Everything above SHOULD work, but there must be something else going on in your code.  Good luck!

Comment: Ok ... the problem was that we were working with improperly formatted JSON. We reformatted the list to proper JSON and it works beautifully.

Comment: Ahhh!  So frustrating!  Glad you managed to get it working though.

Answer (score 0):

So while I was trying your problem on fiddle I came across a problem and that is ng-model="searchName" is not binding to the model value.

And the reason was there was a space between

```
ng-[space]model. //also ng-model should be in red in your code above but it is in red and black..:P
```

So it might be possible that this could be the issue with this.

One more this do not use any other parameter with filter like you did here
use this simple form.

```
<li ng-repeat="employee in ds.employeeList | filter : searchName">
```

Here is my fiddle with the working solution [Fiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kmk7yeey/)

```
<div ng-app="directory" id="searchSection" ng-controller="DirectoryController">
<input id="searchValue" type="text" ng-model="searchName" />
<div id="listView">
<ul>
  {{searchName}}
    <li ng-repeat="employee in employeeList | filter: searchName">
    <p>{{employee.name}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('directory', []);

app.controller('DirectoryController', ['$scope',           
function($scope){
    $scope.searchName = 'Fi';
    $scope.employeeList = [{name : "First Employee", salary : 100}, {name : "Second Employee", salary : 200}];
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. It's working now with the changes suggested by Patrick Grey. The fundamental problem was improperly formatted JSON. However, as originally written, I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can not because the mechanism json is limited to the domain you belong. To do this you must use the jsonp